# Show 404 error in CodeIgniter whe url is wrong

Tags: php, codeigniter, seo, http-status-code-404

I have a problem with 404 error in CodeIgniter. My controller:

```
public function show($id = 0)
{
$review = $this->site_reviews->get_review($id);


if ($review)
{
          .....
}
else
{
    show_404();
}
```

Now if my link is blog.com/article/134 all is well but if I add at the end of link for example blog.com/article/134?678678sdss no error..I want to show 404 when the link is like this.

Help me please guys

Comment: Where you create show_404() function ?

Comment: @er_Rajendraa The `show_404()` function is provided by CodeIgniter - see its [Error Handling](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if $id is, in fact, numeric.

Have you allowed query strings in your CodeIgniter setup on purpose? Disabling them will result in an exception also (assuming you don't intend to use them elsewhere and also assuming the ? in your question wasn't just typed unintentionally).

```
public function show($id = 0)
{
    if(!is_numeric($id))
        show_404();

    $review = $this->site_reviews->get_review($id);

    if ($review)
    {
       .....
    }
    else
    {
        show_404();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter already have functions for error handling. Check this link.
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html